# Integer Solutions for linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, integer-programming

What are the different methods for solving a linear equation with integral Solutions? Which one is preferred over other? What is the best method?

For example, 3x + 5y = 12309834576, How do I find solutions to this equation? (Integral Solutions).

I have tried many google searches and pretty many documents and different methods like benzier etc. However couldn't decide which one is better.

I'm a computer science student, hence comparisons in terms of Order of Algorithms makes great sense to me.

Comment: Linear or Diophantine equations follow the rules of modular arithmetic.  In particular, $ax+by$ can represent every possible integer multiple of GCD($a,b$).  Since GCD$(3,5)=1$, your equation is guaranteed to have at least one integer solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$ 3x + 5y = 12309834576=12309834576(3\cdot2-5)$$

$$\implies 3(x-12309834576\cdot2)=-5(y+12309834576)$$

$$\implies \frac{5(y+12309834576)}3=12309834576\cdot2-x(\text{ which is an integer as }x \text{ is})$$

$$\implies 3|5(y+12309834576)$$

$$\implies 3|(y+12309834576)\text{ as }(3,5)=1$$

$$\implies y+12309834576=3z$$ where $z$ is any integer

Comment: good answer :-) . (+1)

Answer (score 3):

$$ 3x + 5y = 12309834567 \Rightarrow x = \frac{12309834567 - 5y}{3} $$

but $$ x \in \Bbb Z \Rightarrow  1230983467 - 5y \equiv 0 \pmod 3 $$

$ 1230983467 \equiv 1 \pmod 3 $ and $ 5y \equiv -y \pmod 3 $

$$ \Rightarrow 1 + y \equiv 0 \pmod 3 \Rightarrow y \equiv -1 \equiv 2 \pmod 3 \Rightarrow y = 3n + 2 \Rightarrow x = 4103278186 - 5n $$

$$ 3(4103278186 - 5n) + 5(3n + 2 ) = 12309834567 $$

$$ x ,y \in \Bbb Z \Rightarrow n \in \mathbb{ Z} $$

Comment: Generalizing this method, it seems to be of the form: 
`ax + by = c` *=>* `x = (c - by)/a` *=>* `c - by ≡ 0 (mod a)`
followed by finding values `c1` and `b1` congruent to `c (mod a)` and `b (mod a)` such that `c1/b1` is an integer. For eg., here `5y ≡ -y (mod 3)` was used instead of `5y ≡ 2y (mod 3)` because the latter leads to `y ≡ 1/2`, a non-integral value. So here, `b1` is -1 instead of 2 (which is what the programming code `5 % 3` would have returned). [contd. below]

Comment: ... Is there a straightforward way of finding the `c1` and `b1` values conducive to the task? Something other than a trial-and-error search among all values congruent to `c (mod a)` and `b (mod a)`?